# How can I pass values between call_backs in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am new to Matlab. Now the task is to show the title in the GUI and keep updating the title when the script is running.

I create a GUI called Interface, so the script in Main is

```
Interface(title);
```

in the GUI

```
function Interface_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to Interface (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for Interface
handles.output = hObject;
handles.title = varargin{1};
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

I pass the title to handles.title.

In the call_back function of teh static text:

```
title =get( handles.title,'Value');
set(handles.text1,'String',title');
```

it keeps giving me error message saying that i am reading "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array."

Thanks for the help

Comment: `set(handles.text1,'String',title');` there is a `'` after `title` which does not belong there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to have:

```
set(handles.text1,'String',handles.title); % assumes the title input (and therefore handles.title) is a string
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Just make sure your callback function for the static text is passed `handles` as an input. Also, you don't say how `handles.text1` is defined, I assume you have defined it before attempting to set its `String` property.